# Detecting Mailing Address Similarity

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

We have problems with members trying to sign up multiple accounts to take advantage of referral rewards and free trial incentives.  We require a mailing address and validate it against the USPS but have found this still doesn't provide enough protection and it's still too easy for a user to change an element on there address like "line 2" and have it still be valid.

What is the best away to detect if a different user has already signed up with an address?

Example of address variations:

59 Grant Ave
Floor 2

59 Grant Ave
Suite 2

The problem with anything resembling exact comparisons is that the a street address may have multiple tenants in different apartments / offices etc.

We are using Rails 3, MySQL, Memcache, Sphinx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We face a similar problem, although in a different context. There's not that much you can do, we basically wrote a method that tries to identify possible duplicates based on normalized phone number, normalized street address, [Leveshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of name and address, physical distance when geo-coding the address etc. Finding out if something really is a duplicate still needs a human, but at least you can reduce the number of possible candidates significantly.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  We haven't tried the Leveshtein distance yet, so maybe that's the next step.

Answer (score 0):

It requires intelligence to do it reliably, so you can forget about an algorithm. I think that the best you could do is to report addresses which are similar to ones already submitted and then leave it to a person to decide.